# How to plot non-square Seaborn jointplot or JointGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to plot my non-symmetric data using Seaborn's JointGrid. I can get it to use an equal aspect ratio, but then I have unwanted whitespace:

[image: Seaborn 2D heatmap jointplot with extra white space]

How do you remove the padding? The documentation for both [jointplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) and [JointGrid](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid) simply say

> size : numeric, optional
>
> > Size of the figure (it will be square).

I also tried going into feeding the `extent` kwarg to both jointplot and JointGrid, as well as `ylim` with no luck.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.normal(0.0, 10.0, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, 1000)
joint = sns.jointplot(x, y)
joint.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, kde=False)
joint.ax_joint.set_aspect('equal')  # equal aspect ratio
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is your problem with the aspect ratio of the figure or of the hexbin cells?

Comment: Hi @mwaskom, the figure itself. I'd like to get rid of the padding and make it non-square, as my data is my coordinates are not square.

Comment: I would suggest just setting up the figure yourself using matplotlib commands.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Stumbled upon this question looking for the answer myself. Having figured it out I thought I'd post the solution. As the `jointplot` code seems quite insistent on having the figure square I don't know if this is considered bad practice, but anyhow...

If we look through the `jointplot` code and follow it into `JointGrid`, the `size` parameter to `jointplot` (and equally `JointGrid`) is used in the following expression:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(size, size))
# ... later on
self.fig = f
```

So to get a non-square `JointGrid` plot, simply run:

```
grid = sns.jointplot(...)
grid.fig.set_figwidth(6)
grid.fig.set_figheight(4)
grid.savefig("filename.png", dpi=300)
```

for a 6x4 figure.

Answer (score 4):

For those who use Seaborn into a Jupyter Notebook, I suggest calling `set_figwidht()` and `set_figheight()` just after the `sns.jointplot()` command.

```
my_plot=sns.jointplot(x="K",y="errori",data=risultati , kind="scatter")
my_plot.fig.set_figwidth(13)
```

[Jupyter Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nnBm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `ylim` and `xlim` parameters, which will limit the x and y axis to the tuple ranges you specify:

e.g.

```py
sns.jointplot(x="n_estimators", y="learning_rate", data=data,
              color="#172235", height=8, ratio=10, space=0,
              ylim=(0, 1.1), xlim=(-20, 310))  # <-- this
```