# seaborne jointplot - how to get rectangular plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909515/how-to-plot-non-square-seaborn-jointplot-or-jointgrid) which shows how to get a rectangular plot. The code runs. But I was wondering how to print this image on python screen? i tried `grid' but it prints as below

```
grid
Out[91]: <seaborn.axisgrid.JointGrid at 0x1fbb7e76cf8>
```

Comment: What environment are you talking about here? Showing the figure is the same as with any other matplotlib plot, usually `pt.show()`. But you may also just state `fig`  if `fig` is the figure object.

Answer (score -1):

If you run all lines together then it will display the plot that you want. Dont run line by line.